# Running Another Project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project

In my eclipse workspace, I have a library project that I am working on and I have another project set up that I use for testing.

When I click `Ctrl+F11`, I cannot run my library because library cannot be run. Is there a way to launch my testing project when I try to run the library project?

I really hate moving my mouse up to the green button at the top and selecting another project to run. In Visual Studio, there is a project option to run another project instead of the one being developed.

Comment: try after setting your testing project as default/active project

Comment: And how do I do that? I can't find such option in Eclipse.